# How can I pass an arraylist to a constructor in Java?

Tags: java

I have this class `BookDto`:

```java
public class BookDto {
        private int  id;
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private List<CategoryDto> category; 
        private int copies;
        
        public BookDto(int id, String title, String author, List<CategoryDto> category, int copies) {
            this.title = title;
            this.id = id;
            this.author = author;
            this.category = category;
            this.copies = copies;
        }

        //getter and setters
}
```

In my main function I am trying to initialize `BookDto`:

```java
BookDto addBook = new BookDto(0, "abc", "xyi", List<CategoryDto> list, 1);
```

But `List<CategoryDTO>` is throwing an error?

Comment: Decleare the array outside the constructor then pass it to it.

Comment: What error it throws? It is straightforward only.

Answer (score 2):

Your `List<CategoryDto> list` is a variable declaration, like `int i` or `String b` , you need to pass a value.

Directly, like the others

```
BookDto addBook = new BookDto(0, "abc", "xyi", Arrays.asList(), 1);
```

Using a variable

```
List<CategoryDto> list = Arrays.asList();
// List<CategoryDto> list = Arrays.asList(new CategoryDto(.., ..));
String title = "abc";
String author = "foo";

BookDto addBook = new BookDto(0, title, author, list, 1);
```